# When can hidden input types useful ? Google home page

Tags: html

I just happened to look at Google home page for input types while creating a web extension. I noticed that there are 4 hidden input types. Unhiding them does not reveal if they will be ever useful for human inputs.

When can be hidden input types be useful ?

[image: hidden inputs for reference]

Comment: Tracking user data. Passing data from the homepage to the search engine. Hidden inputs are VERY useful.

Comment: [Google It](https://www.google.co.in/search?ei=VlhAW8fUBMnvvAS9upLwDg&q=why+use+hidden+input&oq=why+use+hidden+input)